# Unable to query sub document mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've schema like this and i', trying to get the document from the array using _id. This is my first Mongo project that I'm working, please help me how can I achieve the. I basically want to retrieve the sub document corresponds to the id and update some data in that.

```
    var PhoneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            type: String,
            number: String
        });

        var StudentSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
            name: String,
            dept: String,
            phone: [PhoneSchema]    
        });

var Phone = mongoose.model('Phone',PhoneSchema);
var Student = mongoose.model('Student',StudentSchema);
```

I've tried the following ways, but none of them are working.

Method 1: When I tried the same in the console it is giving me the parent document along with the sub document that corresponds to the phoneId

```
Student.findOne({"phone._id":new mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(phoneId) }, {'phone.$':1}, function(err,     student)       { 

}
```

Method 2: As per the mongoose documentation to retrieve sub documents, in this case I'm getting exception saying phone is undefined

```
Student.phone.Id(phoneId);
```

I've fixed this by removing Schema from the below query

```
Student.findOne({"phone._id":new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(phoneId) }, {'phone.$':1}, function(err,     student)       { 

}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? a StudentSchema document or PhoneSchema document ?

Comment: I wanted to get the phone schema document and update the phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tried to solve your requirement. The following code did the job.

```
var PhoneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            type: String,
            number: String
        });

var StudentSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
            name: String,
            dept: String,
            phone: [PhoneSchema]    
        });

var Phone = mongoose.model('Phone',PhoneSchema);
var Student = mongoose.model('Student',StudentSchema);

var newPhone = new Phone({
    type: 'ios', number: '9030204942'
});

var newStudent = new Student({
    name:'Pankaj',
    dept:'cse',
    phone:newPhone
});

// newStudent.save(function(err, ph) {
//     if (err) return console.error(err);

// });

Student.findOne({"phone._id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId('587e6409e06170ba1708dc21') },{_id:0,phone:1}, function(err,     phone)       { 
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(phone);
});
```

Find the following screenshot with result
[image]

Comment: I do get the result when I try this in mongo shell, but when I try the same using mongoose it is not returning any documents. This is the method 1 that I posted above in my question. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Earlier you had this in the query : 
{"phone._id":new mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(phoneId) }, {'phone.$':1}

Once you changed it to:
{"phone._id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId('587e6409e06170ba1708dc21') },{_id:0,'phone':1}

it worked right ?
The soln works in mongoose. I have sent the screenshot of the same.

Comment: My soln had two things : removing the keyword Schema and add _id:0 in the projection. I think u hadn't noticed and assumed it to be same as your method #1

Comment: Yes, you are right Pankaj I overlooked it and in fact and I didn't know they are different in behavior. I'll mark your answer as accepted.